# Query is not working in Postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.5

I want to fetch data from dynamic tables. I am adding string in table name but I am getting error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getHRName(id text) 
RETURNS text 
AS $$ 
   select fullname from 'hr'_user_profile where hr_id = id)) 
$$  
LANGUAGE sql;
```

I am getting error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'hr'"
> LINE 4:    select fullname from 'hr'_user_profile where hr_id = id))...
> ```

Comment: You need [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for that

Comment: Is there any way to add a string with table name after from  in select query ?

Comment: This smells like a really bad database design. It would be better if you properly normalize your data model. E.g. a single table `user_profile` with a `code` column. Then your query will be as simply as `select fullname from user_profile where code = 'hr' and hr_id = ..`

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but my client doesn't understand this situation. Please suggest me if you have any solution.